# Как корректно распарсить XML в Oracle средствами SQL, XMLtable() и XQuery

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, xmlparser, plsql

В таблице БД Oracle есть ряд строк, в BLOB'ах которых лежат XML такого вида:

```
<ComplexData>
    <Name>ComlexName1</Name>
    <Value>some_value</Value>
</ComplexData>
<ComplexData>
    <Name>ComlexName2</Name>
    <Value>some_value</Value>
</ComplexData>
<ComplexData>
    <Name>ComlexName3</Name>
    <Value>some_value</Value>
</ComplexData>
```

**Пытаюсь отобрать все строки, в бинарных полях которых нет секции:**

```
<ComplexData>
    <Name>ComlexName2</Name>
    <Value>some_value</Value>
</ComplexData>
```

Пытаюсь сделать так:

```
select
 p.guid p_guid
 from pts.p
inner join 
  cp_data cp on p.cpp_guid = cp.guid and cp.guid != 'E63193AB-9C0D-39E4-E043-A2157F0A1417',
  xmltable('for $i in //RootNode/ComplexData where $i/lower-case(Name) != ''comlexname2'' return $i' passing xmltype(p.src_doc, 0) 
columns 
  v_name varchar2(50 char) path 'Name') add_data
  where p.register_date between to_date('15.10.2015 00:00:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
  and to_date('22.10.2015 23:59:59', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') 
  and p.is_active = 1);
```

Собственно пытаюсь перебрать в цикле XQuery по условию: **lower-case(Name) = ''comlexname2''**, но тогда строка все равно выбирается, но уже с **ComlexName1**.

Как корректно перебрать все строки и выбрать те, в которых нет ComlexName2?

Заранее благодарю!

Comment: Полагаю, нужно использовать функцию `existsNode`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если lowercase так необходим и нет других дополнительных условий, которых вы не указали (например выборки данных из этого xml поля), то так:

```
select
 p.guid p_guid
  from pts.p
 inner join 
   cp_data cp on p.cpp_guid = cp.guid and cp.guid != 'E63193AB-9C0D-39E4-E043-A2157F0A1417'
 where p.register_date between to_date('15.10.2015 00:00:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
and to_date('22.10.2015 23:59:59', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') 
and p.is_active = 1

and not exists(select 1 from 
   xmltable('for $i in //RootNode/ComplexData where $i/lower-case(Name) = ''comlexname2'' return $i'
            passing xmltype(p.src_doc,0) columns  v_name varchar2(50 char) path 'Name') )
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ, тестирую.1. А как быть без lowercase если comlexnameX имеет рандом регистр?

Comment: Ну так я же дал запрос который работает С lowercase. т.е. при любом регистре.  Просто, если бы такого условия не было, то запрос был бы гораздо проще

Comment: 2. Выборка значения как-то облегчит запрос? (select from (select) или что-то подобное)...

Comment: Нет, выборка значений явно не облегчит, а усложнит. Скорее всего заставит клеить xml-таблицу еще раз в запрос.

Comment: Эх, тяжеловастый запрос, но выхлоп корректен! Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Если я правильно понял вопрос и структуру данных, то можно использовать `XmlExists`:

```
select p.guid p_guid
  from pts.p
inner join 
  cp_data cp on p.cpp_guid = cp.guid and cp.guid != 'E63193AB-9C0D-39E4-E043-A2157F0A1417'
where
      not(XmlExists('/RootNode/ComplexData[lower-case(Name) = "comlexname2"]' passing xmltype(src_doc, 0)))

  and p.register_date between to_date('15.10.2015 00:00:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
  and to_date('22.10.2015 23:59:59', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') 
  and p.is_active = 1;
```